# Enable Service Topology on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm using k8s with kubeadm version 1.17. I'm trying to enable Service Topology feature gates but I can't. Documentation say to use "--feature-gates="ServiceTopology=true,EndpointSlice=true". I tried to use that in "kubeadm init"... But kubeadm say that is not available to the cluster. Can you help me? That is the documentation that I'm following: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/enabling-service-topology/

Answer (score 3):

It's not a flag of kubeadm. You need to enable it for each kubernetes control plane component such as controller manager, API Server, Scheduler, Kube proxy. The yamls for each of these components located at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` location on all the master nodes need to be modified to add the feature flag `- --feature-gates=ServiceTopology=true`

API Server yaml for example

```
root@kind-control-plane:/# cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 172.18.0.2:6443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=172.18.0.2
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --feature-gates=ServiceTopology=true
```

Edit:

For [kube proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#kube-proxy) a custom kubeadm config file need to be created to add the feature flag

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
...
---
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
FeatureGates:
  ServiceTopology: true
```

Reference [here](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes@v1.18.3/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta2?tab=doc)

Comment: Thank you! So, after the change, how can I apply this changes on my cluster?

Comment: It will automatically be applied by kubelet..to force apply just remove the yaml from that location and place it back

Comment: After the change, I have the following error: "The connection to the server 10.50.11.133:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Comment: check if API Server pod is running after the change. kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: kubectl get pods get the same error, but using "sudo docker ps", I can see that the pod "k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-k8s..." is paused.

Comment: I tried in my setup and it worked. Have you added the parameter at the end of command section in the yaml?

Comment: Thank you, I set  " --feature-gates=ServiceTopology=true,EndpointSlice=true" and that works. But my services stopped now. My pods can't connect to my services.

Comment: You need to create a kubeadm configuration file for that https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#kube-proxy

Comment: Ok, should I reset cluster with "kubeadm reset"?

Comment: yeah reset it and init it with a kubeadm config file

Comment: Glad to know that worked check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: For the Kube Proxy configuration, the key is actually `featureGates`, not  `FeatureGates`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (kubeadm version 1.18.2), it works with the following kubeadm configuration .yaml file (podSubnet is there because I am using Flannel CNI).
The key of kube-proxy is "featureGates" as mentioned in https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kube-proxy/config/v1alpha1#KubeProxyConfiguration

```
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
apiServer:
  extraArgs:
    feature-gates: "ServiceTopology=true,EndpointSlice=true"
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    feature-gates: "ServiceTopology=true,EndpointSlice=true"
scheduler:
  extraArgs:
    feature-gates: "ServiceTopology=true,EndpointSlice=true"
networking:
   podSubnet: "10.244.0.0/16"

---
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
featureGates:
  ServiceTopology: true
  EndpointSliceProxying: true
```