# Service Topology in k8s 1.17 doesn't works

Tags: kubernetes

I enabled a service topology in k8s, but when I create the following service the request is not redirected to local pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  topologyKeys:
    - "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Comment: enabled EndpointSlice?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. When I create a service, a endpointslice and a entpoint is created, but that doesn't works.

Comment: I have a cluster with two worker and one master. Then, I create da nginx depoloyment with two pods, and a service for that pods. I created a pod with a busybox image for tests. When I take a get to nginx service from the busybox image, the nginx pod on the same node should answer the request. Right?

Comment: enabled feature flag in all components including kube proxy

Comment: where is kube proxy config file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable Service Topology on k8s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288296/enable-service-topology-on-k8s)

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you so much.