# Enable Service Topology on k8s: kube-proxy config

Tags: kubernetes, service, kubeadm, topology, kube-proxy

I got stuck on the same problem of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288296/enable-service-topology-on-k8s/62820142#62820142) and couldn't make it work.
When I try to edit `kube-proxy` using `kubeadm` and the config file as hinted, I get the following error:

```
sudo kubeadm init --config ~/kube-proxy-custom.yaml

I0709 17:02:12.954172   67469 initconfiguration.go:207] loading configuration from "/home/andrea/kube-proxy-custom_old.yaml"
W0709 17:02:12.954627   67469 strict.go:54] error unmarshaling configuration schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"kubeproxy.config.k8s.io", Version:"v1alpha1", Kind:"KubePro
 while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field KubeProxyConfiguration.featureGates of type map[string]bool
v1alpha1.KubeProxyConfiguration.FeatureGates: ReadMapCB: expect { or n, but found ", error found in #10 byte of ...|reGates":"ServiceTop|..., bigger context ...|kubepr
"ServiceTopology=true","kind":"KubeProxyConfigurati|...
```

With `kube-proxy-custom.yaml` as:

```
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
featureGates: "ServiceTopology=true"
```

I don't know if it's a go problem or if I'm doing anything wrong. I've tried with both k8s 1.17 and 1.18.5, go 1.13.5 and 1.14.4.
Thank you for any feedback

Comment: Can you try featureGates: "ServiceTopology: true"

Comment: Thank you for your response, but didn't work, same response.

Comment: what is the version of kubeadm and kubernetes?

Comment: I've tested with both 1.17.0 and 1.18.5

Comment: I have edited the other answer with correct config yaml..check that